# How to retrieve data of the extreme years based on a particular variable from a data.frame in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, sorting, ggplot2, tidyverse

I know the `plot` generated using below `code` would be pretty messy because the data is generated using `uniform distribution`. I want to `select` only 5 years where we observed highest value based on `Variable A`. That means, values for `Variable X` may not be the high values as we are conditioning selection based on `Variable A`. Multiple peak in any particular year should be considered as one occurrence. Once the top 5 years are sorted, i would then like to have a `plot` like below.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

set.seed(1500)

FakeData <- data.frame(Date = seq(as.Date("2001-01-01"), to= as.Date("2010-12-31"), by="day"),
                             A = runif(3652, 10,100),
                            X = runif(3652, 5,500)) %>% 
            mutate(Year = year(Date), JDay = yday(Date))

ggplot(FakeData, aes(JDay, A, col=as.factor(Year)))+
  geom_line()+
  theme_bw() +  labs(col = "Year", x = "Month of the year", y = "Levels (m)")+ 
  theme(axis.text = element_text(size = 14), axis.title = element_text(size = 16, face = "bold"))+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(1,32,60,91,121,152,182,213,244,274,305,335), 
                     labels = c("Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"),
                     limits = c(0,365), expand = c(0, 0))
```

**Output**

for example, in Figure below, i am `plotting` almost 38 years data, however, i am interested in only 5 years where we have highest value for the `Level`. so i want to select only those five years for further analysis.
[image]

Comment: `FakeData %>% group_by(year) %>%filter(which.max(A))` or so.  This seems much a matter of filtering to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
```

Find the maximum value for A in each year, sort in descending order, and extract the top five years to use as a filter to the complete dataset for plotting.

```
top_yrs <- 
  FakeData %>% 
  group_by(Year) %>% 
  summarise(maxA = max(A)) %>% 
  arrange(desc(maxA)) %>% 
  top_n(5)

  
FakeData %>% 
  filter(Year %in% top_yrs$Year) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(JDay, A, col=as.factor(Year)))+
  geom_line()+
  theme_bw() +  labs(col = "Year", x = "Month of the year", y = "Levels (m)")+ 
  theme(axis.text = element_text(size = 14), axis.title = element_text(size = 16, face = "bold"))+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(1,32,60,91,121,152,182,213,244,274,305,335), 
                     labels = c("Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"),
                     limits = c(0,365), expand = c(0, 0))
#> Warning: Removed 1 row(s) containing missing values (geom_path).
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-07-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>